# Why is this code returning an error about the shape of neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

When I tried running this code:-

```py
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
dataset = pd.read_csv ("/content/dataset/cancer.csv")
x = dataset.drop(columns = ["diagnosis(1=m, 0=b)"])
y = dataset["diagnosis(1=m, 0=b)"]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, input_shape = x_train.shape, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000)
```

on Epoch 1, I got the error:-

```
Epoch 1/1000
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-a5e6a9bff808> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1377, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1360, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1349, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1126, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/input_spec.py", line 298, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_10" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 455, 30), found shape=(None, 30)
```

Can you help me understand what is going on? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code arises from using an inaccurate input shape for your neural network model. You've used `input_shape=x_train.shape` which doesn't correspond to the number of features in your dataset.
To resolve this, you should specify the correct input shape that aligns with the 30 features in your dataset.

```
# Here is the line of code that is causing error:
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, input_shape=x_train.shape, activation="sigmoid"))
    
# Here is the modified line of code:
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, input_shape=(30,), activation="sigmoid"))
```